# How to access instance properties of a jQuery widget within Backbone.js classes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js

I'm working on a jQuery widget that internally uses Backbone.js.
Here the collection creates the models, the view creates its own subviews:

```
Serializer = function(options, element){
  this.element = element;
  this.data = options.data;
  this.collection = new Serialize.Collection(this.data);
  this.view = new Serialize.View({ el: this.element, collection: this.collection });   
};

$.widget.bridge("serialize", Serializer);
```

[$.widget.bridge](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-jquery-ui-widget-factory-bridge/) provides a friendly wrapper for creating instances of the widget and passing in options (here the `@vars` are set by Rails):

```
$('#item').serialize({
   data: <%= @data %>,
   name: '<%= @name %>',
   keys: '<%= @keys %>'
 });
```

The models and views created later need access to the options of the widget instance. I solved this so far by setting the options on the collection itself:

```
this.collection = new Serialize.Collection(this.data, options);
```

And referencing them later where they are needed (e.g. in a view):

```
var keys = this.model.collection.keys
```

But this gets messy and is not that flexible.

For a single instance you could set `Serialize.Config = { // options }`, and access it globally. But for multiple instances, each instance needs its own config.

So my question is, is there a clean way to access the widget instance and its options within the Backbone classes, without passing it as an argument?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you would like to render each widget instance based on the options you pass to the widgets.

Backbone.js Views are by convention a good place to store these options. Especially since you have one view per widget.

Thus, I would do the following:

```
Serializer = function(options, element){
  // add DOM node and collection to the options hash
  options.el = element;

  // create view and pass options
  this.view = new Serialize.View(options);   
};
```

When you render the widget (presumably with `this.view.render()`) you have access to all the options you passed into `Serializer`:

```
Serialize.View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        // create collection
        this.collection = new Serialize.Collection(this.options.data);

        // register events if needed
        this.collection.bind('add', this.render_one_element_of_the_collection);
        this.collection.bind('fetch', this.render_whole_collection);
    },

    render: function() {
        var data = this.options.data;
        var keys = this.options.keys;
        // etc

        // do something with your variables

        return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a good approach. I like the idea of one master view corresponding to the widget instance that initializes everything. I would probably also move creating the collection inside the master view, thought it starts to feel a bit 'inception' :)

Comment: Actually, that would be even cleaner! The collection is part of the master view, so it can be safely created in there. Changing the script above accordingly.